# Extract list element by successive / cascading index chain

Tags: r, list

```
ll<-list(list(c('A', 'B', 'C'),"Peter"),"John","Hans")
```

looks like:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "Peter"


[[2]]
[1] "John"

[[3]]
[1] "Hans"
```

Lets say I have the indices in  a list for "Peter" and "B" respectively.

```
peter.ind <- list(1,2)       # correlates with ll[[1]][[2]]
B.ind     <- list(1,1,2)     # correlates with ll[[1]][[1]][[2]]
```

#### So how can I most effectively extract a "tangled" list element by its cascaded index chain?

Here is my already working function:

```
extract0r <- function(x,l) {
    for(ind in l) {
        x <- x[[ind]]
    }
    return(x)
}
```

call function:

```
extract0r(ll,peter.ind) #evals [1] "Peter"
extract0r(ll,B.ind)     #evals [1] "B"
```

#### Is there a neater alternative to my function?

Comment: maybe `extract0r <- function(ll, l) Reduce(function(x, y) x[[y]], l, init=ll)` ?

Comment: Should be in the answers @chinsoon12

Comment: you can mark jogo's answer. i got my inspiration from him and its the same idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```
ll <- list(list(c('A', 'B', 'C'),"Peter"),"John","Hans")
my.ind <- function(L, ind) { 
  if (length(ind)==1) return(L[[ind]])
  my.ind(L[[ind[1]]], ind[-1])
}

my.ind(ll, c(1,2))
my.ind(ll, c(1,1,2))
# > my.ind(ll, c(1,2))
# [1] "Peter"
# > my.ind(ll, c(1,1,2))
# [1] "B"
```

The recursive function has a (relative) clear coding, but during execution it has an overhead for the deep function calls.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this.

For example, you can build the commands from character strings:

```
my.ind.str <- function(L, ind) {
  command <- paste0(c("L",sprintf("[[%i]]", ind)),collapse="")
  return(eval(parse(text=command)))
}
```

With your example, I had to convert the lists of indices to vectors:

```
my.ind.str(ll, unlist(peter.ind))
[1] "Peter"
my.ind.str(ll, unlist(B.ind))
[1] "B"
```